# Load an image before the files in AngularJS 1.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, document-body

In the index.html page I put a .gif before all the  tags that laod the files. Then, with JQuery, I removed that loader. But it didn't work. A blank page was shown, because it was waiting for load some .js files.
So, I created a script that load the files dynamically.

This is the html code:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
        <head>
         ...here I'm loading all css files
        </head>
        <body>
            <!-- This is the loader -->
            <div id="loader" style="background:url('URL_IN_BASE_64')"></div>

            <div ng-cloak ng-controller="MyAppController">
                <div ui-view></div>
            </div>

            <script>
                (function () {
                    var fileList = [
                        "vendor/angular/angular.min.js",
                        "vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js",
                        "vendor/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js",
                        ....
                    ]

                    function loadScripts(index) {
                        return function () {
                            var e = document.createElement('script');
                            e.src = fileList[index];
                            document.body.appendChild(e);

                            if (index + 1 < fileList.length) {
                                e.onload = loadScripts(index + 1)
                            } else {
                               var loader = document.getElementById("loader");
                                if (loader) {
                                    loader.remove();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    loadScripts(0)();
                })();
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Now, the problem is that the page first loads all the css files, then angular.min.js, then my gif, and then the other files. Why? How can I immediatly load the gif and, suddently, all other files?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Did I see "Angular + jQuery" again? People, please just stop using these two guys together. Use Angular, OR use jQuery, don't use both at the same time. They're completely different things and just don't mix up.

Comment: what's wrong with using standard `<script>` tags?

Comment: @charlietfl I tried, but I had the same problem... the gif was only loaded after 2 or 3 js files

Comment: You are using `ng-cloak`, which will hide everything until it's all loaded.

Comment: @giorgio assuming that associated css rules were created, otherwise it does nothing

Comment: @giorgio I'm not using the ng-cloack on the gif.

Comment: Also loading order in  dev tools network image conflicts with your statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html parser is being blocked while waiting for your css and js files to load. The work around is to load your stylesheets and script files asynchronously. Do the following for all files that you load in your `<head>`, including `table.min.css`, `ng-img-crop.css`, and `angular.min.css`.

For css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" media="wait" onload="if(media!='all')media='all'">
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"></noscript>
```

For js:

```
<script async src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Fun fact: Google will actually punish web pages that block the parser from rendering elements while waiting for resources.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried it, everything is loaded in asynchronous but the gif is loaded about halfway, and after a while, not first

Comment: @panagulis72 How large is the .gif file? This is to be expected if it's a huge file.

Comment: The file it's not so big, it is 7,4 KB

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!--Put this in head tag-->

<link rel="preload" href="link-to-image">
...
<img src="link-to-image">
```

Comment: The <link> in the head, and the <img> in the <body>?

Comment: Yes you can put <link> in head and <img> in body

Comment: It works, in the resources the image loads first... but for a few moments I have the white page: the browser loads all css files, 3 or 4 .js files and then the gif appears in the screen... why? is there a way to display immediately the gif?